# How to configure run/debug bar tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

[image]

How do I configure what's executed when pressing Run or Debug here? This is what I see:

```
> Executing task: cargo run --package myproject --bin myproject <
```

I tried modifying `tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "run",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "label": "rust: cargo run",
            "env": {
                "RUST_LOG": "info"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "cargo",
            "command": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "rust: cargo build",
            "env": {
                "RUST_LOG": "info"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but it has no effect on the task.

I'm trying to set an environment variable (`"RUST_LOG": "info"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) then
[Setting runnable environment variables](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#setting-runnable-environment-variables):
You may add this to your vscode `settings.json` e.g. `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

```
    "rust-analyzer.runnableEnv": {
        "RUST_LOG": "info"
    },
```

Or press `ctrl+comma` then click on top right corner on `Open Settings (JSON)` icon.

And then you are good to Rust:

```
use std::env;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let key = "RUST_LOG";
    match env::var(key) {
        Ok(val) => println!("{}: {:?}", key, val),
        Err(e) => println!("couldn't interpret {}: {}", key, e),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Output:

```
RUST_LOG: "info"
```